# Does/Should Azure Function authorisation apply when the function is called by a logic app in the same Subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Function with a HTTP trigger and have set the authorisation level on the function to `AuthorizationLevel.Function`. When calling the function from something like Postman I have to supply the function-key as I expect and I receive a 200 code when it executes (otherwise i get a `401: Unauthorised Access`).

However when calling the Function via a Logic App within the same subscription (using the Azure Functions action), the Logic App and Function executes successfully without the need for a function Key.

I would expect the Function to still request the function key from the Logic App, unless this does not apply to resources within the same subscription?

Logic App Build:
[image]

Logic App Execution:
[image]

Comment: Please don't link an images to your post. Instead, just embed the image to your question by clicking the image icon on the top of the editor box.

Comment: Apologies! It wouldn't let me because it was my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected. The built-in Azure Function action uses the complete URL of Http trigger hence we don't need to worry about the authentication. It's all by design because once we are able to find the Azure Functions in the logic app(which locates in the same subscription), which means we have access to them.

If you want to provide authentication key by yourself, you could use Http action instead.

Comment: Thanks Jerry! I thought as much, but haven't seen any documentation or resource to confirm this :)

Comment: @JAA Yeah, don't see any doc either. I think this behavior is exactly what logic app want to offer. We only need to call the Azure Function to process, we don't need to care about the settings which are configured in Azure Function itself outside logic app. Anyway, it's always good to get rid of confusion. Could you accept the answer to close your question?